# Python: How to simulate a click using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

**I don't want to use selenium since I dont want to open any browsers.**

The button triggers a Javascript method that changes something in the page.
I want to simulate a button click so I can get the "output" from it.

### Example (not what the button actually do) :

I enter a name such as "John", press the button and it changes "John" to "nhoJ".
so I already managed to change the value of the input to John but I have no clue how I could simulate a button click so I can get the output.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use selenium to do that

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want. Beautiful soup is a text processor which has no way to run JavaScript.

Comment: Other ideas about how I could do that?

Comment: Maybe you can use some "headless" selenium driver like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) ?

Comment: Seems like my only option. Not great but still the best answer I've got here for sure.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is an `HtmlParser` you can't do such thing. Buf if that button calls an API, you could make a `request` to that api and I guess that would simulate clicking the button.

Comment: The button calls a JavaScript function. I don't think I have access to that function.