# How to follow a link that is actually a click button

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I need to fill a form aproximately 100 times a day. I tried with selenium but it is quite slow because it is using a web browser. It's working quite well with mechanicalsoup until I need to click "Accept" button. Clicking it activates other tables that need to be filled but are inactive before clicking this button. I tried to point to the button and then br.follow_link(button) unsuccesfully. I attach the piece of HTML that I need to fake. I'm looking for a way to produce the effect of clicking avoiding using Selenium.

Aceptar

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need JavaScript capability so the button's click would render the tables, but MechanicalSoup doesn't do Javascript.

**MechanicalSoup's [docs](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) says:**

> MechanicalSoup automatically stores and sends cookies, follows redirects, and can follow links and submit forms. **It doesn’t do Javascript**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since it is just a small problem i thought there might be a way to fake the click sending the instruction generated by clicking as it is suggested in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964061/11385987.  There is also this other suggestion with request and sessions... https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6bt8g2/how_can_i_essentially_click_a_button_on_a_webpage/