# Web Scraping, sign in button is greyed out

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

i am creating a python application that goes to my profile on a website and gives me the text on that page. however, i need to log in first, while i can fill in the login information, i cannot actually submit that. once i found out how to use browser.launch_browser() to show me what was happening, i saw that the log in button was greyed out and unable to be clicked. after playing around with the log in page on a real browser, i found out that the button stays disabled until you type a character into the username field.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import mechanicalsoup
import time

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    }

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0')

username = "username"
password = "Pass123"
url = 'https://myschool.compass.education'
loginpage = browser.open(url)
loginhtml = loginpage.soup
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.select_form()
time.sleep(0.5)
browser["username"] = username
time.sleep(0.5)
browser["password"] = password
time.sleep(0.5)
home = browser.submit_selected()
```

im using mechanicalsoup here, but if any of you know of a different module that i can use to fix this problem, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a "click" method:

```
element.click()
```

You can use this to click in the textbox and enter in data.

I've used Selenium for a few projects.  It's very user friendly.

Selenium will open a robot controlled browser and you'll be able to see everything happen in real time.  It's useful for troubleshooting.  If you want to go "headless mode", Chrome has a headless option for its Selenium driver.

The initial install is a bit of a pain.  But is not hard.

Edit:  Wanted to save you the search.  mechanicalsoup doesn't do javascript.  So there's likely no way to get around this problem.
[StackOverflow QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768308/how-to-follow-a-link-that-is-actually-a-click-button)