# How to automatically log in using python

Tags: python, authentication, automation

I want to use python to automatically enter a website, login to it and maybe pressing some buttons or something like that(for example entering an online class automatically).
And I also don't want to use selenium or something like that(I don't want to use web drivers).
And if you are suggesting me the "requests" please tell me how should I do it.

thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use requests or beautifulsoup or urllib for clicking purposes,
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39964037/14252018) is the answer for why you can't

I suggest you to use selenium it is easy to use here is the documentation
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

And you can download chrome driver from here (if you are using chrome):

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

If you want a detailed explanation on how to install driver and start creating some scripts i found a youtube video which explains it all:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iAqUVvytJk&ab_channel=TheAmericanDeveloper